# Prevent self-closing tags in XML produce by SQL Sever

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

With the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
(
    SELECT 
      N'' AS [content1/\*]
    , N'' AS [content2/\*]
    FOR XML PATH('Rows')
)

SELECT @xml
```

I get self-closing tags like:

```
<Rows>
  <content1 />
  <content2 />
</Rows>
```

Is it possible to get this instead, to use in HTML?

```
<Rows>
  <content1></content1>
  <content2></content2>
</Rows>
```

Also, is the following possible, i.e. without the root node?

```
<content1></content1>
<content2></content2>
```

Comment: Try for **Without Root node**  `SELECT '' AS [content1] , '' AS [content2] FOR XML PATH('')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`TYPE` directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190025.aspx) to avoid implicit conversion to string and back to XML:

```
DECLARE @xml XML= 
  (SELECT N'' as [content1],
          N'' as [content2] 
   FOR XML PATH('Rows'), TYPE);

SELECT @xml;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424084)**</kbd>

Output:

```
<Rows><content1></content1><content2></content2></Rows>
```

---

> and if it's possible?
>
> ```
> <content1></content1>
> <content2></content2>
> ```
>
> means without root node.

```
DECLARE @xml XML= 
  (SELECT N'' as [content1], N'' as [content2] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE);

SELECT @xml;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424087)**</kbd>

Output:

```
<content1></content1><content2></content2>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT '' as content1 , '' as content2 FOR XML PATH('Rows')
```

and

```
SELECT '' as content1 , '' as content2 FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: How does it help when you try to assign result to @xml variable? **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424102)**